# Github Actions не переходит к следующему шагу после успешного запуска приложения

Tags: linux, bash, github-actions

**Задача:** написать workflow для сборки, тестирования, размещения на сервере и запуска приложения.

**Что не получается:** у меня возникли проблемы с запуском приложения, а именно - мне нужно, чтобы после успешного запуска приложения job подождал 20 секунд и затем переходил к следующему шагу, НЕ ДОЖИДАЯСЬ ЗАВЕРШЕНИЯ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ. В моем же случае, после успешного старта  приложения, job бесконечно ждет его завершения. Вот как выглядит текущая реализация этого step:

```
          - name: Run application on server
          uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
          with:
              host: ${{ secrets.APP }}
              username: ${{ secrets.USER }}
              key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
              script: |
                   cd applicationFolder
                   ./stop
                   ./start "${{ env.buildFile }}" &
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту задачу или, по крайней мере, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Не завершаете приложение через 20 секунд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка дурацкая. Github actions ждал не завершения запущенного прилоежния, а закрытия ssh соединения.

Comment: И как решили проблему в итоге?

Comment: Используемый мной actions принимает в своих параметрах время, по истечению которого ssh соединение будет прервано.